# Python star symbol in a loop

Tags: python, cpython

I am using CPython and I saw in one example file with a star symbol.
Could you give an explanation what in this context the `*` symbol means?
Here the `pointsets` is a `numpy array` that comes from `pybind11`, because it is an output of C++ code.

Does the `Point(*point)` has something to do with the pointers in C++?

```
polylines = []
for points in pointsets:
    points = [Point(*point) for point in points]
    polyline = Polyline(points)
    polylines.append(polyline)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the star and doublestar operator mean in a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-and-doublestar-operator-mean-in-a-function-call)

Comment: Possible yes, can you confirm that in this loops the start has nothing to do with the C++ code? Just unpacking of positional variables.

Comment: It has nothing to do with C++.

Comment: Thank you yours and answer below explains this to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called unpacking operator.
Here is what's written in the docs:

> An asterisk `*` denotes **iterable unpacking**. Its operand must be an
> iterable. The iterable is expanded into a sequence of items, which are
> included in the new tuple, list, or set, at the site of the unpacking.

It is much like the "`...`" operator from Javascript ES6. ([the spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax))

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists

Comment: Thank you this is what I was searching for.

Comment: @PetrasVestartasEPFL glad to help! consider upvoting/accepting it as an answer.